# Can't display average in Tableau

Tags: sum, average, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to display the average of movie ratings based on a common actor.
When I drag and drop the "score" value in the columns, Tableau assumes I'm talking about SUMs and shows them accordingly and every square is a movie score:

[image]

But when instead of SUM I select Average, it still shows some kind of SUM but this time every little brick is the same value of average:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is it showing the average once for each row instead of once for actor?

Comment: You have some other dimension on some other shelf (detail shelf perhaps) causing you to get one mark per movie instead of one mark per actor. You can spot dimensions in use because they don't have an aggregation function like SUM() or AVG() or MIN() around the field name. So just remove the extra dimension to get the level of detail you want

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be caused by the view's context, which includes Actor and Movie.

To get the average rate of each actor this should work

```
{ FIXED [Actor]: AVG([Rating]])}
```

and the following if you want the overall average rate

```
{ FIXED : AVG([Rating]])}
```

If you want a better understanding of context and Level of detail expressions you can start reading [this](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm).

Comment: The approach above, using LOD calculations, works but hard codes the level-of-detail into the calculation. (that's the point of LOD calcs after all)  Sometimes that exactly what you need to do, but for alot of cases, using LOD calcs is unnecessary and makes the viz a bit more complicated than necessary, and certainly less flexible for data exploration. So my advice is use LOD calcs when you need to, but don't develop a habit of using them every single time. Treat that as a tool that's helpful as your second resort. YMMV. Again, @Nicolaesse's solution is correct, just could be simpler